# Collapse all displaying twice in the Markdown help page

Tags: support, design, markdown

In the [Markdown Editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page, collapse all option is displaying twice.

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to [Markdown Editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page
- click **show more** in bottom of the any section
- click **expand all** option
- scroll to end of the page, there you can see the **collapse** and **collapse all** options twice

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Collapse all - twice]

Since both the **collapse all** option is doing the same operation and the option is not specific to any section, so the repeating is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're each from different sections, it's just a result of having nested collapsable sections, with the nested section being the last thing in its "parent" collapsable section.

It does look a little confusing and the double up of the "collapse all" is a bit redundant so maybe it could be displayed better, but it isn't a bug.

Just to show which section each refers to...

> [image]

Comment: After seeing your comment, I understand that functionality and when I'm going to delete the post, you were answered. I opened this post for future search.

Comment: Yeh I agree it's a bit confusing so I think it's probably worth keeping the question open